# Is it possible to utilize carrier data and WiFi connections simultaneously within an App?

Tags: ios, networking, wifi

The theory in question is that I have a device that emits its own WiFi network. In order to communicate with this device, you must be connected to that WiFi network, but as it does not provide internet, your connection options are blocked.

What would be ideal, is to connect to this device, collect data from it, and transmit/push this data to a server located online via whatever means.

This question has been asked before, but the responses and questions I found were a few years old, and the OS has been updated a few iterations since then.

Is it possible, via Swift or Objective C within a mobile iOS app to utilize the connection of WiFi, but use carrier data to transmit that collected data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the BlueTooth API for this. However, there are two restrictions: 1) you cannot connect to a BlueTooth device in a captive network, and 2) you will not be able to connect to Android devices via BlueTooth.